# Error when building the chosen plugin with grunt

Tags: gruntjs, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to build the [chosen plugin](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) using grunt. I was able to run the build yesterday, but when I tried it today it ran into errors!
I don't know what I have done or what goes wrong. only this error message:

```
D:\git\chosen>grunt build  
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/project.rb:18:in `open': No such file or directory - repos (Errno::ENOENT)  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/project.rb:18:in `entries'  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/project.rb:18:in `generate_files'  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:13:in `block in <class:Server>'  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1385:in `configure'  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:13:in `<class:Server>'  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:2:in `<module:Grunt>'  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grunt-0.0.6/bin/grunt:5:in`<top (required)>'  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/grunt:23:in `load'  
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/grunt:23:in `<main>'
```

How can I get it to work? or at least where do i begin to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the [grunt](http://rubygems.org/gems/grunt) ruby gem installed which conflicts with your task runner grunt. Just uninstall the Ruby gem with: `gem uninstall grunt`.

Comment: Quick note: OSX Mavericks ships with a version of grunt installed within the "system" ruby environment. If running `gem uninstall grunt` shows a blank like, make sure you're using the correct version; maybe `rbenv global system`. Check versions with `rbenv versions`. `rbenv help`